# If a function is continuous between sets with the finite complement topology, then it is constant or finite-to-one

Tags: general-topology, continuity

I'm reading Topology by Munkres and I found this question floating around the internet from an assignment issued in a university topology course some dude took in 2019.

Prove that a function $f:X \to Y$ where both $X$ and $Y$ are taken with the finite complement topology is continuous, iff it is constant or finite-to-one.

In order to prove that a continuous function with respect to this topology is finite-to-one, is it useful to employ the compactness property of X and Y?

$\Rightarrow$

$f: (X,\mathscr T) \to (Y,\mathscr U)$

$\mathscr T$ = {$A \subseteq X | A = \varnothing \cup X - A$ is finite}

$\mathscr U$ = {$B \subseteq Y | B = \varnothing \cup Y - B$ is finite}

Suppose, by hypothesis, that $f: X \to Y$ taken with the finite complement topology is  continuous and let $y \in V \subseteq Y$

$\Rightarrow$

$f^{-1}(V)$ is open in $X$, that is to say $f^{-1}(V) \in \mathscr T$ for any $V \in \mathscr U$ as this is the topological definition of continuity.

But notice under $\mathscr U$ every open set contains all but finitely many points of $Y$, so $Y$ is compact.

$\Rightarrow$

$f: X \to Y$ is continuous so $X$ is compact as well.

$\Rightarrow$

There exists an open covering such that there is a finite subcovering of $X$

$\Rightarrow$

For every open $V$ in $Y$ (and there are finitely many of them), $f^{-1}(V) \lt \infty$ in $X$

Does this make any sense at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you wrote doesn't really make sense. For example, if $f: X \to Y$ is continuous and $Y$ is compact then $X$ need not be compact (in this case $X$ is also compact because every set endowed with the cofinite topology is compact). Also, why do you think there are only finitely many open sets in $Y$? (take $Y = \mathbb{R}$ with the cofinite topology, then all sets of the form $\mathbb{R} \setminus \{x\}$ are open)

Now for the actual solution, first of all, notice that the closed sets in the cofinite topology are precisely the finite ones and the whole space.

$(\Rightarrow)$ If $f$ is continuous then $f^{-1}(\{y\})$ is closed in $X$ so either it is finite for all $y \in Y$ or equal to $X$ for exactly one $y$ (that's because preimages of disjoint sets are disjoint). This implies that $f$ is either finite-to-one (first case) or constant (second case).

$(\Leftarrow)$ If $f$ is constant then it is obviously continuous. Now if $f$ is finite-to-one consider a closed set $F\subset Y$ different from $Y$. Then $F = \{y_1, y_2, \dots, y_n\}$. Notice that
$$f^{-1}(F) = f^{-1}\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^n \{y_i\}\right) = \bigcup_{i=1}^{n}f^{-1}(\{y_i\})$$
which is a finite union of finite sets so it is finite and in particular closed in $X$.